# MATLAB copyfile error: argument must contain a string

Tags: matlab, file

So I have a pretty simple problem I'm trying to solve. I want to create a backup of a file in MATLAB.

Here is my code (I am starting this script from my current directory):

```
backup_dir=strcat(pwd,'/backups/');
cd('../../source_destination/');
source_dir=pwd;
cd(backup_dir);

source_files=strcat(source_dir,'/*.m');
source_file_list=dir(source_files);
source_file_names={source_file_list.name}';

for i=1:numel(source_file_names)
    source_file=strcat(source_dir,'/',source_file_names(i));
    backup_file=strcat(backup_dir,source_file_names(i));
    copyfile(source_file,backup_file);
end
```

Running this gives me the error:

```
Error using copyfile
Argument must contain a string.
```

However, when I actually examine `source_file` and `backup_file`, both variables return a valid string (enclosed by `' '`) and both strings do point to a valid file:

```
>> source_file

source_file = 

    '/Users/me/mydir/cool/source_destination/archive.m'

>> backup_file

backup_file = 

    '/Users/me/mydir/cool/world/scripts/backups/archive.m'
```

Also, the actual content of `source_file_list` is valid.

So why would I be getting this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to dereference the `cell` array contents with curly braces, otherwise `strcat` returns a `cell` array of strings:

```
for i=1:numel(source_file_names)
    source_file=strcat(source_dir,'/',source_file_names{i});
    backup_file=strcat(backup_dir,source_file_names{i});
    copyfile(source_file,backup_file);
end
```

Comment: Thank you! I guess I had assumed (incorrectly) that `source_file_names(i)` would return a string, since when I would actually display it, it showed up surrounded in quotes, while doing `source_file_names{i}` did not show up in quotes.

Comment: @Alex Indeed.  Due to the flexibility inherent in `cell` arrays, they require a special form of referencing to access the actual contents versus the generic element.  It is something to get used to but very powerful.

Comment: I know the problem was the cell array, but instead of using `strcat`, I prefer to use `fullfile`. IMHO much easier to read and understand. `fullfile(source_dir, source_file_names{i});`